# Creating MVC project sometimes adds references?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

So I've been having an issue adding an MVC4 project to my solution. When I add it to an existing solution, it immediately throws warnings that much of the MVC 4 framework dlls cannot be found. However, when I start a new project that is an mvc 4 project on its own, all the references seem fine.

I noticed that in the properties, there is no Path set in the first scenario, but it is set the packages directory in the project in the second scenario but it will not allow me to type anything into the path

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you adding an existing or a new MVC 4 project to solution in case when it doesn't work properly?

Comment: Nope! I actually even removed the mvc4 project from the solution then removed that project directory from the solution directory. Then I tried to create a new mvc4 project within the solution. Same thing.

Comment: In the meanwhile, since I can create the project by itself, I did so and then copied it's package directory over the top of my actual solution. All of the package directories were there but without the dlls. This at least put those back. I added those to source control, hopefully it'll stick together lol. Still don't know what the problem is with creating the project, though.